# Determine if data was sent via intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there any way to determine if a specific boolean value was sent via an Intent? In other words, I know how to send data via an Intent and how to read it back, but I would like to know if data was sent.

The current `getBooleanExtra` method requires a default value, so I can't check if it wasn't sent by using this.

I currently have this:

```
showNavigationDrawer = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(Extras.EXTRA_SHOW_NAVIGATION_DRAWER, false);
```

If the `Extras.EXTRA_SHOW_NAVIGATION_DRAWER` value wasn't set at all, I'd like to do some extra work. Obviously if I get `true` it means it was sent, however if I get `false` there's no way to tell.

Comment: If you get false , it means no value selected, if you get true it means selected. then what is the problem?

Comment: Its doesn't matter what you put by default true or false, and for checking intent  value you can use LOG.

Comment: Send an `int` instead. 0=false, 1=true, -1=not set

Comment: @Ishrat No, because I can send `true` or `false`. What I want to know is if I can see if nothing was sent at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done extracting the intent bundle:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
boolean hasNavDrawerSetting = b.containsKey(Extras.EXTRA_SHOW_NAVIGATION_DRAWER);

if (hasNavDrawerSetting) {
    showNavigationDrawer = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(Extras.EXTRA_SHOW_NAVIGATION_DRAWER, false);
} else {
    showNavigationDrawer = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.hasSideMenu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to check whether your value is coming or not then you can take help of **Bundle** object. You can pass your boolean value through a bundle object. If the **bundle** object is **null** then no value is received in the next activity. But if it is not null then you will surely receive the value of your boolean parameter only **if you put it in the bundle**. It may be **true** or **false** depending upon the value you set. Below I'm providing two code snippets. One is for calling activity and another is one for called activity.

**Calling Activity -->**

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Experimental.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putBoolean("key",true);
        startActivity(intent.putExtra("bundle",b));
```

**Called Activity -->**

```
    setContentView(R.layout.experimental);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");
    if(b != null){
        Log.d("Value",String.valueOf(b.getBoolean("key",false)));
    }
```

Hope I'm able to help you.